# jQuery not functioning as expected in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm sure I will lose points for this as I can't provide specifics of the problem, but I can't figure out which part is causing the problem...

http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/advisors/index.html

Here is an interactive graphic which works fine in chrome. It consists of some variables which change when you click the different buttons in the middle, and some animate functions which use these variables to resize the banks around the outside.

After looking at some other advice I added 'px' to the animate functions but that hasn't had any effect. The strange thing is the simple rollover which also uses the animate function works fine but the more advanced one which uses variables doesn't.

Can anyone see anything in the jQuery which could stop it from functioning? Let me know if you need any more info, thanks

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var title = 0;

    $(".bank").mousemove(function(e) {
        $(this).find('.tooltip').css('left', e.pageX + 10).css('top', e.pageY + 10).css('display', 'block');
    });

    $(".bank").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).find('.tooltip').css('display', 'none');
    });

    var resize = function() {

        $('.bank').each(function() {
            bankName = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];

            var bankSize = window[bankName] * 15;
            var bankNameMargin = bankSize / 2 - bankSize;

            $('.banks .' + bankName).animate({
                width: bankSize + 'px',
                height: bankSize + 'px',
                marginLeft: bankNameMargin + 'px',
                marginTop: bankNameMargin + 'px'
            }, 300);

            if (bankSize == 0) {

                $('.banks .' + bankName).animate({
                    opacity: '0',
                    width: '70px',
                    height: '70px',
                    marginLeft: '-35px',
                    marginTop: '-35px'
                }, 300, "linear", function() {
                    $(this).css({
                        "opacity": "1",
                        "width": "0px",
                        "height": "0px",
                        "marginLeft": "0px",
                        "marginTop": "0px"
                    });
                });
            }

        });

    }

    resize();

    $(".bank").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '+=10',
            height: '+=10',
            marginLeft: '-=5',
            marginTop: '-=5'
        }, 200);
    });

    $(".bank").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '-=10',
            height: '-=10',
            marginLeft: '+=5',
            marginTop: '+=5'
        }, 200);
    });

    $(".button1").click(function() {
        title = 1;
    });

    $(".button2").click(function() {
        title = 2;
    });

    $(".button3").click(function() {
        title = 3;
    });

    $(".reset").click(function() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $('.banks .bank').animate({
            width: '70px',
            height: '70px',
            marginLeft: '-35px',
            marginTop: '-35px'
        }, 300, "linear");
        title = 0;
    });

    $(".button").click(function(e) {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(".tooltip p").remove();
        $(".choose").remove();
        $(this).addClass("active");
        console.log(title);
        if (title == 1) {

            $('.barclays .tooltip').append("<p>Deals: 3</p><p>Percentage: 30%</p>");

            barclays = 4;
            hsbc = 2;
            morgan = 4;
            citi = 2;
            baml = 4;
            jpmorgan = 2;
            goldman = 7;
            ubs = 3;
            suisse = 2;
            deutsche = 3;
            jefferies = 2;
            nomura = 1;
            bnp = 1;
            numis = 0;
        } else if (title == 2) {
            barclays = 5;
            hsbc = 3;
            morgan = 3;
            citi = 2;
            baml = 2;
            jpmorgan = 9;
            goldman = 5;
            ubs = 4;
            suisse = 4;
            deutsche = 5;
            jefferies = 1;
            nomura = 0;
            bnp = 1;
            numis = 3;
        } else if (title == 3) {
            barclays = 0;
            hsbc = 0;
            morgan = 5;
            citi = 2;
            baml = 2;
            jpmorgan = 7;
            goldman = 2;
            ubs = 5;
            suisse = 2;
            deutsche = 4;
            jefferies = 2;
            nomura = 5;
            bnp = 2;
            numis = 0;
        }

        resize();

    });

});
```

Comment: And your code is...what?

Comment: Is there a specific version of IE this doesn't work in?

Comment: I added the jQuery, but it can also be accesses through the link. Why, does it work for you in IE Alex? I'm on a mac but creating it for someone who wants it IE compatible. I don't have access to IE to properly test it

Comment: @bboybeatle: *"but it can also be accesses through the link"* Questions cannot rely on links to be meaningful, not least because links rot, and also people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Remember that your question isn't just for you, now, it's for others in the future.

Comment: You can do whatever you link in terms of code indentation and formatting for your own purposes, but when asking other people for help, take the time to format the code reasonably, perhaps using a service like http://jsbeautifier.org. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: @bboybeatle, there are ways a means to test in IE on a mac. I use a Mac and use VirtualBox to test in IE. Any developer worth his cloth should have access to all browsers. Aaaany way, back to the question. I've tested it in IE10 and it works fine.

Comment: @bboybeatle Microsoft provide free VMs for everything down to XP here: https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools

Comment: Note that the code appears to be falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Given that IE dumps more into the global namespace than most browsers, who knows, maybe there's a conflict of some kind...

Comment: @bboybeatle Are the `barclays` ... `numis` variables defined anywhere? Are we missing a bit of the code?

Comment: OK Thanks guys I will look at those options for testing. @Fly I haven't declared those as variables to start with, should I do that? Sorry I'm fairly new to jQuery

Comment: I added all of those variables at the start ( var barclays = 0; etc.) but that broke it in chrome also

Comment: If you Inspect Element in Chrome you will find this warning "'webkitRequestAnimationFrame' is vendor-specific. Please use the standard 'requestAnimationFrame' instead." 

and in Internet Explorer there exists an error saying 'console' is undefined.. Jus go through them and try fixing them..

Comment: @bboybeatle Like @Crowder said, not declaring them with `var` pollutes the global namespace, and could potentially result in undefined behavior. I also don't see where they're accessed in any other part of the script.

Comment: Thanks @Kaushik but after googling it appears the vendor specific warning isn't a problem. I've removed the console log now as that was just for my workings out. Fly, they are accessed using the class name for each bank ... ( bankName = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]; ... var bankSize = window[bankName]*15;  )

Comment: Ive put all the variables outside the document.ready function and removed the console log and it all seems to be working! Thanks

Comment: My work here is done, although IE 8 doesnt allow border radius, or the background-size: contain; property. I guess thats for another question

Comment: I confirm it is working now with IE 11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the console.log.

IE has problems with it, and it will cause it to break if the Debugger is not active (Developer Tools panel open).

What you can do is to replace the console.log with a new function. I like the Paul Irish solution:

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/